# Where do you store json files in a Xamarin forms app for ios and android apps

Tags: android, ios, json, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and would like to include some read-only data in a json file to be deployed with the package that will be used as a local data store. How do you add this resource to the respective project types? ie iOS and Android.

Comment: "local data store" - do you just want to read from it, or also write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the json file in the Froms file directory, then click the file->Properties->Build Action to select Embedded resource.

You can get it using the code below:

```
var resourcePrefix = "MyApp.";//your project name.
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourcePrefix + "aaa.json");//your json file name
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var reader = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```